# Naming convention для iphone 6, 6+, 6S, 6S+

Tags: ios, xcode

Какие особенности именования картинок для iphone (например Launch image) 6, 6+, 6S, 6S+
если

Например: 4-inch (имя-568h@2x)

Comment: в каком плане "как называть" ? как хочешь, так и называй

Comment: есть форма для 4дюймового (-568h@2x), как для 4,7 и 5,5 ?

Comment: я бы даже сказал, что закрытие этого вопроса не совсем оправдано. Очень специфичный для iOS вопрос.

Comment: Я бы предложил использовать ImageAssets… Это убирает проблему с именованием файлов…

Answer (score 3):

кажется так

iPhone 6s Plus and iPhone 6 Plus **(@3x)**

iPhone 6s, iPhone 6, and iPhone 5 **(@2x)**

iPhone 4s **(@2x)**

iPad and iPad mini **(@2x)**

iPad 2 and iPad mini **(@1x)**

iPad Pro **(@2x)**

[ссылка](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

для Lunch File нужно так

для iPhone 6:

750 x 1334 **(@2x)** для Книжный

1334 x 750 **(@2x)** для Альбомный

для iPhone 6 Plus:

1242 x 2208 **(@3x)** для Книжный

2208 x 1242 **(@3x)** для Альбомный

[ссылка](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1)

[для иконок ссылка](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html)